# lm(y~poly(x1, x2,x3, degree=2, raw=TRUE), data)

Tags: r, lm

Is

```
lm(y~poly(x1, x2,x3, degree=2, raw=TRUE), data)
```

equal to

```
lm(y~x1 + x2 + x3 + x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 , data)
```

?

If yes, why do we need to set `raw=TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this yourself easily:

```
DF <- data.frame(x1 = 1:2, x2 = 3:4, x3 = 5:6)
with(DF, poly(x1, x2, x3, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
#     1.0.0 2.0.0 0.1.0 1.1.0 0.2.0 0.0.1 1.0.1 0.1.1 0.0.2
#[1,]     1     1     3     3     9     5     5    15    25
#[2,]     2     4     4     8    16     6    12    24    36
#attr(,"degree")
#[1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "poly"   "matrix"
```

The column names show the product of the three variables and the degree each variable has in this product. E.g., `1.1.0` means `x1^1 + x2^1 + x3^0`.

Of course, you see this also in the output of the regression model.

You need `raw = TRUE` if you want the coefficients to correspond to raw polynomials, i.e., `alpha0 + alpha11 * x1^1 + alpha12 * x1^2 + ...`. If you don't need that, you should *not*  set `raw = TRUE` because [orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) have some desirable properties for regression analysis.